# Issues with alignment when it comes to flex

Tags: html, css

I have two issues with my flex I require assistance resolving. I created a fiddle here to access: https://jsfiddle.net/dmj5yscz/

Issue 1: I am unable to move the elements to the center (see red in screenshot). Tried margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto in various places but no luck. (note: should only happen if width is no more than 1144px)

Issue 2: I want the text to be vertically aligned in the center (any screen width)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    <!-- newsletter section -->
    
    <div class="newsletter_section">
    <div class="newsletter_inner_section">
    <div class="newsletter_left content-box">
    <img src="xxx">
    </div>
        <div class="newsletter_mobile_col">
    <div class="newsletter_center content-box">
    <p class="newsletter_text_section">Text1 </p>
            </div>
    <p class="newsletter_input_section">Text2 </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    /* newsletter section */
    
    .newsletter_inner_section{
        display:flex;
    }
    
    .newsletter_gif{
        width:150px;
        height:auto;
    }
    
    .newsletter_left,
    .newsletter_center,
    .newsletter_right{
        display:inline-flex;
    }
    
    .newsletter_left{
        width:auto;
    }
    
    .newsletter_center{
        width:100%;
    }
    
    .newsletter_right{
        width:40%;
        justify-content:flex-end;
    }
    
    .newsletter_text_section{
        color:black !important;
        font-size:20px !important;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    
    /* Media Newsletter section only */
    
@media (max-width:1144px){
    
    .newsletter_right,
    .newsletter_center{
        width:auto;
    }
        
    .content-box {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
    }
        
    .newsletter_inner_section{
        justify-content:center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:row;
    }
    
    .newsletter_text_section{
        padding-left:15px;
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
        
    .newsletter_mobile_col {
      flex-grow: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
}
    
    @media (max-width:565px){
        
        .newsletter_inner_section{
        flex-direction:column;
        }
        
        .newsletter_left{
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }
        
    .newsletter_gif{
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set: `flex-grow:1;` which is making second flex-div to take available space. Please remove this and it will be center aligned

```
.newsletter_mobile_col {
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

And yes, use `align-items:center;` on flex container to make it center aligned across cross-axis.

```
@media (max-width: 1144px){
 .newsletter_inner_section {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;/* here */
   }
}
```

And if you want to behaviour on all screens, just write the above CSS outside media query :)

Comment: Ah I thought flex-grow is something different but yes this works perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To display flex items into center

[Flexbox link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
(justify content)

For the second, set another display flex with: flex direction column and center it